# how to sign on a canvas using cucumber and selenium on ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

I'm using ruby to write automation and a part of it is to write something on a canvas that I can track using an id selector (I need to drag and drop the cursor to create a non-empty canvas).
I tried doing it in many ways but couldn't find out the way to do it.

Comment: `tried doing it many ways`. which ways have you tried so far?

Comment: @sircapsalot I read documentations and tried most of what they said (and some fire events) but it didn't work for me so I wanted to know if anyone else worked it out.